# NetworkManager Wi-Fi enablement button unselectable

Tags: linux, wifi, networkmanager

I have a [Gigabyte Q2532](http://www.gigabyte.co.za/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3793#kf) laptop and `Enable Wi-Fi` of NetworkManager is not selectable. As for the device, here is the relevant entry from `lspci`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

I can see the driver is loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep ath
ath9k                  83980  0 
ath9k_common           12728  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              345710  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    21417  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              386825  1 ath9k
cfg80211              366201  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
```

I also installed the firmware package, `firmware-atheros`, but I still get the same issue.

Manually loading the driver gives me this on `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome kernel: [ 5758.818796] ath: phy1: ASPM enabled: 0x42
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome kernel: [ 5758.818799] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome kernel: [ 5758.818801] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome kernel: [ 5758.818803] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome kernel: [ 5758.818803] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome kernel: [ 5758.820362] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'ath9k_rate_control'
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome kernel: [ 5758.820686] ieee80211 phy1: Atheros AR9285 Rev:2 mem=0xffffc90004ec0000, irq=17
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> rfkill3: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy1/rfkill3) (driver ath9k)
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> WiFi now disabled by radio killswitch
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> (wlan0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> (wlan0): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'ath9k' ifindex: 7)
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> (wlan0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlan0, iface: wlan0)
Jun 27 22:36:53 thome NetworkManager[1004]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlan0, iface: wlan0): no ifupdown configuration found.
```

NetworkManager config file:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

The other config file:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

NetworkManager is at **0.9.8.0**, and...

```
$ uname --all
Linux thome 3.11-rc4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.11~rc4-1~exp1 (2013-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It didn't work with Linux versions **3.9** and **3.10** as well.

Also:

```
$ iwconfig wlan0 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

Comment: Take a look at this Q on askubuntu: [How to let NetworkManager manage WLAN interface after upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90993/how-to-let-networkmanager-manage-wlan-interface-after-upgrade)

Comment: Purging and reinstalling did not help. Thanks though.

Comment: What distro is this?

Comment: This is Debian Jessie (testing).

Comment: Do you've `wlan0` in your `/etc/network/interfaces` and `managed=false` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`?

Comment: @Alex I have no `wlan0` entry in the former, and have `managed=false` in the latter.

Comment: Any of these `iface, mapping, auto, allow-*` in `interfaces` could match, none? Have you seen already https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#Wired_Networks_are_Unmanaged ?

Comment: @Alex I have updated the Question.

Comment: There's a wpa_supplicant.log also? https://wiki.gnome.org/NetworkManager/Debugging

Comment: I'm sure that you have already done a lot of troubleshooting regarding this. But here is a list of apparently trivial issues reported by people who have experienced similar problems -- may be you could have a glance: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1063057.html

Comment: Can you set it up manually w/o network manager: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188

Comment: Does `iwconfig` shows anything? (if this tool exists in your systen). Also you could try alternative network daemon, wicd: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD to see is it a dumb and faulty network manager problem or really your interfaces are mess.

Comment: @IBr I have updated the Question.

Comment: @IBr I also had no luck with `wicd`.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=355404) help? Especially [this post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=355404#p361850) and [this one](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=355404#p505074)

Comment: @JosephR. it works now, see the Answer.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@JosephR](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80939/networkmanager-wi-fi-enablement-button-unselectable?noredirect=1#comment133298_80939) for pointing to [this post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=355404), which alerted me to the idea that I did not press the right buttons. There is a Fn key combination that actually enables Wi-Fi... I do feel stupid, given I been frustrated by this issue for months now.

Comment: This should be a sanity check comparable to the immortal "Is it plugged in?" :D I once spent hours installing and re-installing a wireless driver only to find out that I had the wireless hardware button set on disable.

Comment: This is one of those cases where one needs a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the Network Manager applet? It can frequently 'freeze'. I'd `killall nm-applet`, start `nm-applet` again and see if it is fine then.

Comment: I think this is ruled out  because trying `wicd` failed. See the OP's comment on the question.

Comment: What does *freeze* mean? Other than the fact that the WiFi button is not selectable, the applet is fully functional.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. In my case the solution I found was only specific to Sony Vaio labtops though.

I'm a seasoned user of Linux,(33 years) so when my Wi-Fi suddenly stopped working I was a bit surprised.

The "Enable Wi-Fi" check box in the NetworkManager Applet would not toggle to "ON", meaning I could not check it no matter how much I tried.

I worked through most of the solutions on forums

rfkil  - to see if blocked, all good
iwconfig - to see if the interface was there, all good

Plus comparing Wi-Fi/Hotspot setups to a working machine, albeit a earlier version of Debian.
all good though.

**SOLUTION:**
When I sat down on the couch I must of accidentality toggled the WIRELESS switch on the Sony Vaio to OFF!

**( located at the front left hand side edge of the laptop )**

I wish I had known about this before I spent hours crawling through posts, so I thought I'd post this. I hope this post saves someone time.

I signed up for Linux decades ago, and I'm  still not complaining. :)